# How to split a long audio file based on quiet parts?

Tags: matlab, audio

I have a few long audio files (about 1 hour each) which contain words and their meanings in a way that a person says a word and its meaning and then waits 1 second, then says another word and so on. I want to split this long audio file into many short files that only contain a word and its meaning. As I'm a programmer, I want to do it using some sort of programming languages. I want to do it with `Matlab` or any other programming languages. I'm familiar with `Matlab`, `C`, `C++` and `Java` but I don't know where to start or how to do this.
Can anyone please tell me how can I do this and what tool or programming languages should I use?

Thank you

Comment: There is a submission on MC [Silence removal in speech signals](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28826-silence-removal-in-speech-signals) that might help you

Comment: @brodroll Thank you very much